# JWT access vs refresh tokens

Tags: jwt, access-token

I have an application that I want to secure with JWT tokens. For what I have read, the common practice is to have very short lived access tokens and very long lived refresh tokens, so that when an access token is required a refresh token can be used to get one.

How is this better than having just long lived access tokens then? I am storing the tokens "securely" in the browser, in secure httpOnly cookies... both of them together. Considering it is common practice also to have a freshness attribute, and to require (when needed) a fresh token for some activities... does this make the use of refresh tokens abit overboard?

Comment: relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233685/how-does-a-jwt-refresh-token-improve-security, in fact, there may be a lot of questions here that might help you: https://www.google.com/search?q=jwt+access+refresh+token+site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a JWT refresh token improve security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233685/how-does-a-jwt-refresh-token-improve-security) But for the record: it's quite common to have long-lived access tokens, you just _don't use JWTs for that_. A token that is also stored server-side - often a cryptographically random blob - can be more secure than a JWT, and is also revocable so you don't have to keep the lifetime short.