# Do we really need refresh tokens?

Tags: authentication, account-security, oauth, authorization, access-token

I have read a number of posts of many people expressing their confusion around the extra security gained from using an access token and a refresh token to control access to a resource API.
Picking up from this post [how-does-a-jwt-refresh-token-improve-security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233685/how-does-a-jwt-refresh-token-improve-security) on this site;
The author of the question made his case: if an access token can be stolen so can the refresh token, so what's the point of issuing a refresh token?
The accepted answer is that unlike an access token, a refresh token can be revoked. If a hacker were to gain access to a long lived access token, there's no way to invalidate the access token(without invalidating access tokens of all users). Therefore, necessitating the use of short lived access tokens and revocable refresh tokens. Use cases for revocable refresh tokens include logging a user out from all sessions, user password change.

While I am convinced that a combination of refresh token and short lived access token  makes the authentication/authorization process more secure, I think there is a better way to achieve the same result without the need for a refresh token at all. All we need to do is store the creation date of the access token in the token itself and create a table in the database to store (user id, revocation_timestamp) pair. Whenever we suspect an access token has been compromised, we update the revocation_timestamp to the current time.
A hacker with a stolen access token will have access to the resource server for the short lifetime of the access token. When we receive an expired access token, we check in our database for revocation-timestamp corresponding to the user id in the token. If the token was issued later than the time in revocation-timestamp, we issue the user a new access token otherwise they have to supply their credentials. And that is it, the hacker is blocked. No need to store long refresh tokens in our database.

I would love to get feedback on my approach. Do we really need refresh tokens?

**ADDITION**

Another security feature of refresh tokens is that they can't be used twice. If a malicious user gained access to a refresh token and used it to get a new access token, that new refresh token would be invalidated when the legitimate user tries to use the old refresh token.
This too can be achieved with just the access token. We will need to store the timestamp of issuance of latest access token in our DB. Whenever a request for a new access token is made, we compare the timestamp in the provided token with the timestamp of the most recent access token issued. If the timestamp in the provided token doesn't match that stored in our DB, we know this access token is being reused so we stop all active tokens from being able to generate new tokens by setting the revocation-timestamp in our DB to the current time.

The last bit that needs to be addressed is a malicious user continuously supplying the same old compromised token to the server thereby invalidating our legitimate user session repeatedly. In that case, we store another piece of information to capture the most recent date a user supplied their credentials. If the timestamp in the old token is more recent than the last time the user supplied their credentials, we prompt all users to login again when the compromised access token expires. If the last login date of the user is more recent than timestamp in the compromised token, we ignore the threat and keep our user logged in.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986005/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-refresh-token for some interesting reading on this subject.

Comment: @mti2935 I have read through the stack overflow post: Because the refresh tokens are sent only to the authorization server, there's lesser risk of a malicious user gaining access to it unlike access tokens that are sent to resource servers that could be compromised. Otherwise, all other security benefits of refresh tokens can be achieved with just the access token alone.

Comment: What if the resource server is also acting as an authentication/authorization server (jwt web application), any benefits of refresh tokens)?

Comment: Your question is a little amorphous. "Do we need refresh tokens?" Yes, and the standards explain why. "Isn't my proposed alternative better?" Maybe, you don't give nearly enough info to come up with an opinion, and that has nothing to do with your title question. So, this really comes down to "why can't we combine access tokens and refresh tokens and make it possible to revoke access tokens?" or "why are access and refresh tokens split?" These are things we can answer from the standards. We can't really evaluate your high-level description of an alternative.

Comment: @schroeder Writing focused questions can be challenging. Refresh tokens make it possible to 'revoke' access tokens while still giving a user a good UX. What I really want to know; firstly does my approach also solve this problem and two, are there any drawbacks / limitations in using my approach? I believe you can do some analysis if the approach can actually work from the high level description I have provided.

Comment: I am actually building an SPA using jwt for authentication. I can't issue long lived jwts because I can't invalidate them when there's need. Refresh tokens solve this problem but I believe my approach is simple to implement and straightforward. Are there any security vulnerabilities, performance issues etc in using my approach?

Comment: I think that if you added all these details, we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: @schroeder I decided to migrate the question to Stack Overflow. I have included all the details of what am i trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77886097/seeking-feedback-on-jwt-authentication-without-refresh-tokens-for-a-web-applicat

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of literature both from identity vendors / platforms and from the folks behind OAuth and OpenID Connect as to why refresh tokens are necessary. Here are some of the benefits

1. **Make access tokens short-lived** thus reducing the threat they pose if they are stolen. Quoting Loginradius's documentation

> The main purpose of using a refresh token is to considerably shorten the life of an access token. The refresh token can then later be used to authenticate the user as and when required by the application without running into problems such as cookies being blocked, etc.

The OP states that RT can be stolen. That's true and there's also a way to mitigate that. Quoting the same site

2. **Rotate Refresh Tokens**

> If a refresh token is compromised (someone else got their hands on it or, even worse -- steals it), the individual would not only gain access to the resources provided by the API but also the amount of time the access has been granted would be more. Now that's a dreadful scenario for developers and users alike.
>
> Having said that, counter-measures such as Refresh Token Rotation and Automatic Reuse Detection help limit the destructive nature -- and highlight the benefits of these refresh tokens.

BTW this question has already been [tackled here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060478/is-a-refresh-token-really-necessary-when-using-jwt-token-authentication).

Lastly some great resources:

- https://oauth.tools/
- https://oauth.net/2/refresh-tokens
- https://gotopia.tech/episodes/25/the-secrets-of-oauth-2

Comment: what if I say I can achieve the security of detection of reuse of refresh tokens another way with just the access token? Whenever we issue a new access token, we also store the timestamp of issuance in our DB. If a malicious user got access to the token, that access token will expire after a short time then we issue a new access token and store the new timestamp in our DB.

Comment: A legitimate user would also attempt to get a new token with the old token already used by the malicious user to generate a new token. The timestamp in this token will be less than that in our DB and we know the token is being reused.